# insert javascript variable into mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have created a quiz page named quiz.php. It contains javascipt which calculates the correct answers of the user (amountCorrect variable). I want to insert this variable to mySql db via scorepage.php but my code doesn't work. Any help ???

Here is the part of javascript

```
    function show_score() {
    var amountCorrect = 0;          
    ...
    if(radio.value == "right" && radio.checked) {
    amountCorrect++;
    }
    }
    alert("Correct " + amountCorrect + " out of 6");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/Istoselida/scorepage.php",
        data: "score1=" + amountCorrect,
        success: function () {
            $('ul#posts').prepend(wall_post);

        }
    });
    }
```

And here is the part of the scorepage.php

```
    include('db2.php');
    $member_id=$_SESSION['member_id'];
    $result=mysql_query("select * from studentstable where id='$member_id'")or die(mysql_error);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $score1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['score1']);
    $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE studentstable SET Varscore1 ='$score1' WHERE id= $row");
```

Comment: what about it doesn't work?

Comment: first query makes no sense ....you already have the ID for the update

Comment: You are probably missing session_start()?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass `$row` in the `UPDATE` statement. `$row` is an array, not a value. Try:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE studentstable SET Varscore1 ='$score1' WHERE id= $row[id]");
```

Comment: It didn't work. Sorry if it's misunderstood, but the variable has to be inserted in the appropriate row of the table which is the number of the user id (and the user who runs the quiz)

Answer (score 0):

put row id $row['filedname']

```
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE studentstable SET Varscore1 ='$score1' WHERE id= ".$row['id']);
```